# Can I uninstall/remove SQL Server 2008/2008r2 after installing SQL Server 2012?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express, localdb

I just finished installing SQL Server 2012 and I was wanting to take advantage of Localdb. I chose not to upgrade my SQL Server 2008 R2 and to install 2012 as a new instance. Unfortunately, I realized afterward that Entity Framework defaults to sqlexpress when available even though Localdb is specified in the web.config connection string.

I tried stopping the service for sqlexpress, but this throws an exception when trying to run the site from Visual Studio.

Any advice on how I can remedy this?